# Matplotlib returning incorrect years in xaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib

When running the below code, my output x axis is returning years between 1970 and 1972 when I am expecting 2020 and 2023. The input dates which I am using in the CSV file and the format of `data['Settlement Date']` is `'%d/%m/%Y'`.

I have confirmed in the code when running `print((data['Settlement Date'][0].strftime('%Y')))` returns 2020 and not 1970.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fileLocation = r'C:\FileLocation'
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(fileLocation,'BQH2024'+'F.csv'), parse_dates=False)
data['Settlement Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Settlement Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
ylabel = 'Traded Price ($/MW)'
ylabel2 = 'Daily Volume (MW)'
xlabel = 'Date'
yformat = '%.0f'
title = 'QLD ASX Based Contract FY2023-2024'

#plotResults(xAxis, listOfSubplots, listOfIndex, xlabel, ylabel, yformat, title, legend = True, grid=True, dateFormatter = True)
print((data['Settlement Date'][0].strftime('%Y')))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax.set_xticklabels(data['Settlement Date'])
ax2.set_xticklabels(data['Settlement Date'])

data['Settlement Price'].plot(kind='line',ax=ax, zorder=2, label = 'Settled Price')
data['LAWR'].plot(kind='line',ax=ax, zorder=2, label = 'Trade Weighted Rate')
data['Traded Volume'].plot(kind = 'bar', ax = ax2, label = 'Traded Volume')

ax.yaxis.grid()

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())

ax2.set_ylim(0,200)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.set_ylabel('Contracted Rate ($/MW)')

ax2.set_ylabel('Traded Volume (MW)')

ax.set_title(title)
ax.set_xlabel('Trade Date')


fig.show()
```

[image: output figure from script with wrong dates]